# Perl strptime parse millisecond

Tags: perl, strptime

I need to parse some time string that comes in a format like ddmmyyyyhhmmssXXX. The XXX part is millisecond. In the below code Im ignoring the millisecond part. It works but I get the error:

```
garbage at end of string in strptime: 293 at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Time/Piece.pm line 482.
```

Whats the proper format that I should use.

```
$time = '11032014182819802';
$format = '%d%m%Y%H%M%S';
$t = Time::Piece->strptime($time, $format);
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the milliseconds? Just ignore them? Use them to round the seconds field? Or something else?

Comment: I calculate difference between two times. Most of the times it is OK if the difference is in seconds. But in special cases I might need difference in millisecond level aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Time::Piece->strptime(substr($time, 0, -3), $format);
```

since [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) does not support milliseconds.

Comment: This is specific to the example, it does not cover cases where milliseconds are not at the end of the string (and asking about those would be considered a duplicate of this question)

Answer (score 1):

If you care about the milliseconds and want to preserve them, you'll need to look into using something else (e.g., [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime::Format::Strptime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-Strptime/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm)  if you want to parse milliseconds, then you may try this:

```
my $Strp = new DateTime::Format::Strptime(
                                pattern     => '%d%m%Y%H%M%S%3N',
                        );

my $date = $Strp->parse_datetime("11032014182819802");
print $date->millisecond ,"\n";
```